# XQuery On SQL Server - Performance Issues

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, xquery-sql

Working on XQuery in SQL Server. My understanding was that using CROSS/OUTER APPLY for the nodes would help improve performance, however the top query (below) performance SIGNIFICANTLY worse than the lower. Can anyone help explain why that is, and perhaps any pointers on XQuery performance? I've searched all of the questions I can find but nothing seems directly on point.

**Poor Performer**

```
SELECT x.ApplicationId
    , t.value('(reportId/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS ReportId
    , t.value('(reportType/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS ReportType
    , t.value('(tracking-number/text())[1]','varchar(50)') AS TrackingNumber
    , n.value('(firstName/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS FirstName
    , n.value('(middleName/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS MiddleInitial
    , n.value('(lastName/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS LastName
    , ssn.value('(ssn/text())[1]','varchar(50)') AS SSN
    , dob.value('(dob/text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS DateOfBirth
FROM #xml x
    CROSS APPLY x.xmlResponse.nodes('/xml-response') t1(t)
    OUTER APPLY t1.t.nodes('personPii/applicantInformation') t2(ai)
    OUTER APPLY t2.ai.nodes('name') t3(n)
    OUTER APPLY t2.ai.nodes('ssn') t4(ssn)
    OUTER APPLY t2.ai.nodes('dob') t5(dob)
```

**Better Performer** -why?

```
SELECT x.ApplicationId
    , x.XMLResponse.value('(/xml-response/reportId)[1]','varchar(100)') AS ReportId
    , x.XMLResponse.value('(/xml-response/reportType)[1]','varchar(100)') AS ReportType
    , x.XMLResponse.value('(/xml-response/tracking-number)[1]','varchar(50)') AS TrackingNumber
    , x.XMLResponse.value('(/xml-response/personPii/applicantInformation/firstName)[1]','varchar(100)') AS FirstName
    , x.XMLResponse.value('(/xml-response/personPii/applicantInformation/middleName)[1]','varchar(100)') AS MiddleInitial
    , x.XMLResponse.value('(/xml-response/personPii/applicantInformation/lastName)[1]','varchar(100)') AS LastName
    , x.XMLResponse.value('(/xml-response/personPii/applicantInformation/ssn/ssn)[1]','varchar(50)') AS SSN
    , x.XMLResponse.value('(/xml-response/personPii/applicantInformation/dob/dob)[1]','varchar(30)') AS DateOfBirth
FROM #xml x
```

Comment: The queries aren't equivalent unless you have one node all the way in the xml. You will only get one row from the second one?

Comment: They return identical recordsets, and the same number of rows - however many are in the temp table #xml.

Comment: that's what i mean. if xml contained multiple dob nodes etc, then you wouldn't get them...

Comment: if your xml structure is flat, you don't need to use nodes

Comment: Ah gotcha...yeah both ssn and dob are nested (eg <ssn><ssn>12345</ssn></ssn>) but can't do anything about that; it's how we receive the data from our vendor.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Please show the XML you are trying to query

Comment: @siggemannen Slept on it and it finally clicked. CROSS APPLY would only apply in the event that a value had multiple nodes (thinking maybe address history, where there could be multiple addresses per individual over the years). Otherwise, bottom example makes sense. Thanks for being patient with me!

Comment: Yes, exactly! Your second query is optimized for single node xml structure

Comment: We can't help you further unless you show us the XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an example of nodes vs simple xml:

```sql
create table #data (xml xml)
insert into #data
select '<root><data><field>X</field><field>Y</field></data></root>'

select xml.value('root[1]/data[1]/field[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from #data d

select n.value('(text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from #data d
cross apply xml.nodes('root/data/field') t(n)
```

Here, you can see the difference how nodes work. The first version cannot simply fetch more than one field value

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example for you.

Notable points:

- XML is inherently hierarchical, so the `CROSS APPLY` simulates one-to-many relationship between states and their cities.
- It is always better to use `.../text()` for the untyped XML elements for
  performance reasons.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<root>
   <state>
      <StateName>Florida</StateName>
      <Abbr>FL</Abbr>
      <Capital>Tallahassee</Capital>
      <cities>
         <city>
            <city>Miami</city>
            <population>470194</population>
         </city>
         <city>
            <city>Orlando</city>
            <population>285713</population>
         </city>
      </cities>
   </state>
   <state>
      <StateName>Texas</StateName>
      <Abbr>TX</Abbr>
      <Capital>Austin</Capital>
      <cities>
         <city>
            <city>Houston</city>
            <population>2100263</population>
         </city>
         <city>
            <city>Dallas</city>
            <population>5560892</population>
         </city>
      </cities>
   </state>
</root>';

SELECT state.value('(StateName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS State
    , state.value('(Abbr/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Abbr
    , state.value('(Capital/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Capital
    , city.value('(city/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS city
    , city.value('(population/text())[1]', 'INT') AS population
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/state') AS t1(state)
    CROSS APPLY state.nodes('cities/city') AS t2(city);
```

**Output**

| State | Abbr | Capital | city | population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Florida | FL | Tallahassee | Miami | 470194 |
| Florida | FL | Tallahassee | Orlando | 285713 |
| Texas | TX | Austin | Houston | 2100263 |
| Texas | TX | Austin | Dallas | 5560892 |